# Is there any way to delete the wrong comment in CVS (don't have admin rights)

Tags: cvs

Read carefully before marking duplicate.

Hi I am facing a issue while commiting a file in CVS I gave a comment and accidently pressed the enter.

so My whole directory in CVS got commited with the same comment.Now i want to revert back.
I browsed alot but i could not find a solution so that i can do it without admin rights.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, but not for you, and it's somewhat convoluted (only one message  for one file can be changed at a time). This is dome by sending the -m switch to cvs admin command.

Generally changing the history of a repository is frowned upon. Alternatively you can make a small change to the files that need a different commit message, and commit them again.

Here is [the relevant page](http://www.dig.cs.gc.cuny.edu/manuals/CVS/cvsbook.html#Changing%20A%20Log%20Message%20After%20Commit) from the manual.